# Issue pushing to heroku, app not compatible and remote rejected

Tags: python, git, heroku

So I'm new with heroku and attempting to push my project into heroku. I got a similar error at first, and then I made a temporary branch and I was able to push it and then open it, but my project wasn't sure, just the welcome screen. Then, I tried doing it the normal way, and  it told me it wasn't sure what the default language was, so I logged into heroku and made sure the build pack was set to python, but now I'm getting this error and it still doesn't push. I have my .git folder in the root, and when I am pushing, I am in the root. I made sure to check git status and it says I'm on my temp branch, not sure how to switch it back to master, but before I made the change, it said there was nothing to commit, working tree clean.

```
 remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shrouded-sands-60485.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-sands-60485.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-sands-60485.git'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.3
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.10.2
Markdown==3.1.1
pbr==5.4.5
Pillow==7.0.0
pygame==1.9.6
pytz==2019.1
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
stevedore==1.32.0
virtualenv==16.6.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
```

**directory **

```
  .
├── 11_env
│   ├── bin
│   ├── lib
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── dating_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── chat.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── tag.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── dating_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

Comment: You need to be on the master branch and the `requirements.txt` has to be present. the `pre-receive hook` error is caused here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect it cannot find your requirements.txt.

Comment: @TinNguyen How do I get back on the master brancgh

Comment: `git checkout master`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding a `runtime.txt` manually specifying the python version and a `requirements.txt` by doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the project root directory, be sure that git is tracking both files by `git add <filename>` and `git commit <filename> -m <message>`.